# Creating native dom element, with data that jQuery's data() will use

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I'd like to create a DOM element, natively, attaching data to it. and than, later, create a jQuery element of it, setting (automatically) these data to be available through the data() function.

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x. ???? // add the data {a: {x: 4, y:6}}
x = $(x);
var obj = x.data("a")
console.log(a.x); // getting '4'
```

can it be done - and how?

please note that `data-[attrib-name]` won't work since I need complex data.

Comment: And why wouldn't you just use jQuery to create the element

Comment: it is created in a documentFragment first, and the data is set there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.data()` to set data on a native DOM node in jQuery

```js
var x = document.createElement("div");

$.data(x, 'a', {x: 4, y:6});


x = $(x);
var obj = x.data("a")
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great answer, thanks. however i cant save ref' to objects with it. any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @yossi - native data attributes **can't** store objects at all, **only** strings. jQuery on the other hand lets you store complex objects by storing them in memory, in a special object jQuery keeps for associated data, that's why it can store objects in `$.data`. If you wan't to store objects in `$.data` you **have** to create the elements with jQuery.

Comment: OK. Can i access (trying to find it for the last hour) the memory object and set the data "manually"?

Comment: Actually, yes you can, give me a second to demonstrate,

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to add `$.data` to a native DOM node

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `data` attribute, by using javascript's `setAttribute()` like so:

```
var theDiv = document.createElement("div");
theDiv.setAttribute('data-x', '4');
theDiv.setAttribute('data-y', '6');
```

Access them:

```
console.log(theDiv.getAttribute('data-y'));
```

And also access the same with jQuery:

```
$(theDiv).data("x");
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not helping me with complex data and references.